# Using special characters in a string for variables in tcsh script

Tags: tcsh

I want a string to be stored in the variable which is having special characters.

```
String: 'ABC_FGD[34], HDT_EDT[345], KBR_DTI[675]'
```

I tried using the ASCII codes but while printing the variable it is printing the ascii codes.

```
set String = "'ABC_FGD\x5B34\x5D, HDT_EDT\x5B345\x5D, KBR_DTI\x5B675\x5D'"
echo ${String}
```

Output:

```
'ABC_FGD\x5B34\x5D, HDT_EDT\x5B345\x5D, KBR_DTI\x5B675\x5D'
```

Can someone help to print the string properly?

Thanks & Regards,
Parth.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using double quotes should work:

```
> set string = "'ABC_FGD[34], HDT_EDT[345], KBR_DTI[675]'"

> echo "$string"
'ABC_FGD[34], HDT_EDT[345], KBR_DTI[675]'
```

I'm guessing you tried to use `echo $string` without the quotes: you need to quote the variable on *use* to prevent globbing (or use `set noglob`).